# Necesito cambiar el valor de un atributo en un archivo.json por un objeto

Tags: php

Buenas tardes les explico:

En mi base de datos tengo dos **archivos.json** que son los siguientes:

**Usuarios.json** que tiene esto:

```
   [{"codigoUsuario":1,"nombre":"Patricio","correo":"patricio@gmail.com","siguiendo":[1,2,3,4,5]},{"codigoUsuario":2,"nombre":"bob","correo":"bob@gmail.com","siguiendo":[1,2,3,4,5]}]
```

y posts.json que tiene esto:

```
[{"codigoPost":1,"codigoUsuario":1,"contenidoPost":"Lorem ipsum dolor amet doloremque.","imagen":"img/posts/1.jpg","cantidadLikes":1},
{"codigoPost":2,"codigoUsuario":2,"contenidoPost":"Lorem ipsum dolor amet doloremque.","imagen":"img/posts/2.jpg","cantidadLikes":1}]
```

la cuestion es que atravez de php leo estos dos archivos :

```
public static function obtenerUsuarios($codigoSelect){
        $registrosUsuarios = json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/usuarios.json"),true);
        $registrosPosts = json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/posts.json"),true);
        $resultado = array();
        $indiceResultado = 0;
        $indiceSeguidor = 0;
        for ($i=0;$i<count($registrosUsuarios);$i++){
            if ($registrosUsuarios[$i]["codigoUsuario"]==$codigoSelect){
                    $resultado[$indiceResultado] = $registrosUsuarios[$i];//aqui meto todo el usuario a resultado resultado[0]= usuario
                    //Recorrer toooodas los seguidores para identificar cual pertenece al usuario especifica.
                    $indiceSeguidor = 0;
                    $resultado[$indiceResultado]["seguidores"]=array();
                    for ($j=0; $j<count($registrosUsuarios[$i]["siguiendo"]);$j++) { 
                        if($registrosUsuarios[$i]["seguidores"]==$registrosPosts[$j]["codigoUsuario"]){
                            $resultado[$indiceResultado]["seguidores"][$indiceSeguidor]=$registrosPosts[$j];
                        }
                    }
                $indiceResultado++;
            }
        }
        $registrosUsuarios = null;

        echo json_encode($resultado);
    }
```

la cuestión es que necesito que en esa función obtener Usuarios me regrese un array nuevo que seria $resultado , pero que dentro de este vayan los usuarios , dentro de los usuarios los seguidores , y dentro de los seguidores que vayan los posts de los seguidores.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y cual es el problema? Tienes algun error? Que resultado obtienes?

Comment: No es clara tu pregunta. ¿Cómo se determinan las relaciones? ¿Cómo se sabe a qué usuario pertenece un seguidor, a que seguidor pertenece un post?  ¿? Si puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado deseado, mucho mejor.